# Black screen when powering on PC. Fixed by removing power plug, plugging back

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, power-supply, power, desktop-computer

I have a weird problem with my desktop PC. Sometimes (not all the time), after I power up the PC, the display shows a black screen. Nothing shows up. The PC was powered on successfully as I can see the LEDs light up on the casing. To fix this problem, I pressed and hold the power button to shut down the PC first, then removed the power plug. Wait for a pop sound, then plug back the power plug. After doing these steps, the PC boots up normally and the monitor shows the BIOS boot up screen.

I am running Windows 10.

PC configuration:
- AMD Ryzen 7 2700x
- Nvidia GT 710
- Motherboard B450 Aorus pro Wifi 
- DDR4 RAM 16Gbyte 2133Mhz clock
- SSD 1 Terabyte

Comment: I hold the power button to shut off the PC, then pull out the plug.

Comment: Few steps you could try to check: 1.Update video card driver and BIOS from the official website of the manufacturer.2. Change the display resolution to resolve monitor issues.3.Check if even log recorded some errors when black screen happened. 4. Connect the computer to another monitor. If the new monitor works, the original monitor or its cables are faulty. 5. Unplug unrelated hardware devices, such as USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potential causes of a black screen:

1. Installation in progress

   How to fix:

   > The best thing you can do in this situation is to wait, but if it's been anywhere between 3 to 6 hours, then chances are that the installation process is stuck.
   >
   > If the installation is stuck, you should try shutting down your device completely.
   >   [...] disconnect all the non-essential peripherals, including external storage, phone, printer, game controller, network cable, and secondary monitor. If possible, also turn off your Wi-Fi and Bluetooth adapters. Only leave connected to your computer the essentials: keyboard, mouse, and display.
   >
   > Wait 60 seconds, reconnect the battery and power cable, but do not reconnect any of the peripherals, and power on your computer.
   >
   > If this was a mere hiccup, the installation process should resume and complete successfully.
2. Loose Connections and/or Driver issues

   To Fix:

   - Check to see if your display is connected properly to your computer and to power.
   - If possible, change the video port (e.g from VGA to HDMI). There may be a driver that needs to be updated or reinstalled.
   - Disable the discrete graphics card, switching to the integrated one -- this'll tell you if it's your graphics card or the drivers used for it. You can uninstall and reinstall the drivers to see if that helps. If not, I would check to make sure everything is connected to your discrete graphics card properly -- [ASUS Nvidia GT710 Installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NnRkrauYgTs) (This is just the first video I found, but there are plently more if you need them.)
   - Try a different monitor and/or cables -- yours could be dying, have a bad connector, etc.

   > - If the computer isn't detecting the display, then you can try using the **Windows key + P** keyboard shortcut, press **P** again and then **Enter**.
   >     You'll need to repeat this steps a number of times to cycle through all screen options.
   > - [...] use the Windows key + Ctrl + Shift + B keyboard shortcut to wake up your display.
3. Something connected to the computer is causing problems

   Disconnect everything you can so you're only left with the essentials -- i.e. tower, keyboard, mouse, monitor -- restart, then slowly reconnect things one at a time until you find the one causing the problem. Check the drivers for the device, update (and/or reinstall), and restart. If it's still a problem, you'll need to troubleshoot with the product's support center.
4. Other (more complicated or obscure reasons)

   To Fix:

   - Reboot into [Safe Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode)

      Use the troubleshooting tools in the advanced startup menu to try to track down the problem
   - Backup your computer and do a clean reinstall. (It's far from ideal, but it can fix errors from a corrupt OS; and I have found this has worked for me before when Microsoft Support couldn't figure out what was wrong.) You can [migrate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/step-4-user-files-and-settings-migration) over your files, settings, etc. if this solves the problem.
   - Check if the GPU is referenced properly in BIOS. [Someone else had this problem.](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3299085/black-screen-signal-inserting-gtx-710-graphics-card-apu-comp.html)
   - Try [Rolling back the Integrated Graphics Driver](https://appuals.com/fix-geforce-experience-black-screen-windows-10/)

Primary Source: [How to fix black screen problem on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-black-screen-problems-windows-10)